# How to append searches from localstorage to unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, twitter

I am building a TwitterApi application that returns all popular tweets for a word I enter a keyword in a search box.

So far I have 3 buttons, one for *search*, one for *add*, and one for *delete*. When I click on *search*, it searches twitter and when I click on *add* it takes keyword that is searched and puts in into `local storage` so I can use it later. My idea is to show what is stored in `local storage` in one list so I can search from that list later (like saved searches)

My idea was to do that with append:

```
$('#btn-add').click(function () {                
            var inputValue = $("#search-box").val();    
            var currentSavedTweets = localStorage.getItem ("SavedTweets");          
            localStorage.setItem ("SavedTweets", currentSavedTweets + "," + inputValue);                                  
              });
```

Now I tried:

```
$("#btn-add").click(function(){
            $("ol").append("<li> localStorage.getItem(SavedTweets) </li>");
                 });
```

The second part of the code doesn't work. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't take this approach. You've made it hard to retrieve items by storing them comma separated and probably have caused some other gremlins as well.

Take a look at how [this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpZFE/56/) stored a json array in local storage.

```
// load into memory
if (localStorage['tasks']) {
   var tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage['tasks']);
}else {
   var tasks = [];
}
```

...

```
// add the task to the array
tasks.push(val);

// save to local storage
localStorage["tasks"] = JSON.stringify(tasks);
```